# Showing page after loading page

Tags: jquery

I try to show my page after loading the page.

In order to do that,

```
 <div id ="loadingDiv">
        <img src="urltogif">
    </div>
```

I create above div and used the below js.

```
 $('#loadingDiv')
    .hide()  // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

but the gif image is always shown on the page.
What is the reason for this?

Comment: is your jQuery code within a `$(document).ready(function(){//here})` function ?

Comment: I think showing your full code can help us understand what you want and where you're wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you jQuery code is executed after the page has completed loading and the DOM is ready, this can be done using the [`ready()` function in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loadingDiv').hide() // hide it initially
    .ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    }).ajaxStop(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
})​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2AAu/4/) - click the button to start the AJAX request - there is a 5 second delay on the response so you can see the "loading" div

### Update

Based on your comment below - I think you want the `div` shown on page load and hidden when the page is loaded :

HTML :

```
<div id ="loadingDiv">
    <img src="urltogif">
</div>
```

this means its shown by default, the following jQuery will hide is once the page has completely loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loadingDiv').hide();
});
```

Im not sure why you have the AJAX methods in there in this case !!!????!??? or perhaps I have totally miss read you question !

Comment: that's not what i want . I want spinner when page is not loaded.When page is loaded.Spinner must be hidden

Comment: @MertMetin i dont understand what you mean ? so while the page is loading you want the spinner showing ? when the page is fully loaded you want the spinner hidden ?

Comment: yes , the spinner must be shown only page is loading. After loading , it must be hidden

Comment: @MertMetin and how is the "page" loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include document.ready function at the top , so that the jQuery could be executed once the page is loaded completely.